# How to make autocomplete for form dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

i have trouble using autocomplete with dynamic created input. I can't get autocomplete to bind to the new inputs.

This code autocomplete I used on the first input

```js
$(function() {
  $( '#nama-0').autocomplete({
    source: "get_barang.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      $('#kode-0').val(ui.item.kode);
      $('#harga-0').val(ui.item.harga);
    }
  });
});
```

and this new table row with input:

```js
 $('#tambah').click(function() {

  var i = $('input').size() + 1,
  input = '<tr id="box' + i + '">';
  input += '<td><input id="nama-' + i + '" name="nama_input[]" autocomplete="off" class="nama form-control" /></td>';
  input += '<td><input id="kode-' + i + '" name="kode_input[]" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" /></td>';
  input += '<td><input id="harga-' + i + '" name="harga_input[]" type="number" autocomplete="off" class="hitung form-control" /></td>';
  input += '<td><input id="jumlah-' + i + '" name="jumlah_input[]" type="number" autocomplete="off" class="hitung form-control" /></td>';
  input += '<td><input id="total-' + i + '" name="total_input[]" class="total form-control" readonly="readonly" /></td>';
  input += '<td><button id="hapus" class="btn btn-default"><b>Hapus</b></button></td>'
  input += '</tr>';

  $('#box').append(input);


  i++;
  return false;


});
```

i think the problem I guess the problem is in the use of dynamic input id attribute. how to write id of dynamic input, and apply them in autocomplete? any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is because the `#nama-N` element doesn't exist in the DOM when you try to initialise the autocomplete function on it.

To fix this, move your first block of code inside the click handler, after `append()` has been called. Try this:

```js
$('#tambah').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var i = $('input').size() + 1;
  var input = '<tr id="box' + i + '">';
  input += '<td><input id="nama-' + i + '" name="nama_input[]" autocomplete="off" class="nama form-control" /></td>';
  input += '<td><input id="kode-' + i + '" name="kode_input[]" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" /></td>';
  input += '<td><input id="harga-' + i + '" name="harga_input[]" type="number" autocomplete="off" class="hitung form-control" /></td>';
  input += '<td><input id="jumlah-' + i + '" name="jumlah_input[]" type="number" autocomplete="off" class="hitung form-control" /></td>';
  input += '<td><input id="total-' + i + '" name="total_input[]" class="total form-control" readonly="readonly" /></td>';
  input += '<td><button id="hapus" class="btn btn-default"><b>Hapus</b></button></td>'
  input += '</tr>';

  $('#box').append(input);

  // attach autocomplete here as the element now exists in the DOM
  $('#nama-' + i).autocomplete({
    source: "get_barang.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      $('#kode-0').val(ui.item.kode);
      $('#harga-0').val(ui.item.harga);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: the autocomplete in field nama is work, but why field kode and harga not automatically filled? i have change id kode and harga with ('#kode-' + i) and harga ('#harga-' + i), but it not work. can you help me?

Comment: That should work. Try checking the console to see if there's any errors. If not it may be worth starting a new question about how to retrieve custom values from the autocomplete library

Comment: what you have suggestions to get values from the autocomplete library?

Comment: i am sorry the code you give to me is work very well.. i just forgot to write (function(e) { e.preventDefault(). thank you for your help.